Calling a Lambda from a CloudFront function?
My current situation is that we have a 3rd-party content provider with fairly outrageous CDN fees, so we're front-ending them with CloudFront. However, the CDN URL is not tenant-specific so I've implemented a CF Function that checks for our tenant/project IDs in the URL before fetching from the backend. However our devs want rolling Dev->Staging->Prod projects from this provider, so it will no longer be a static list of IDs and no one wants to be responsible for hand-editing that list all the time.
My solution is to simply drop a file containing crypto.createHash('sha256').update(secret + project) into the origin and, on request, fetch this file and validate it as a check to ensure that the project ID is valid. In order to minimize the overhead to each request I would also persist valid/invalid project IDs via a CF KeyValueStore.
I was not really expecting to be able to perform an HTTP request within the scope of a Edge Function, which is confirmed by the http module not being available in the JS2.0 runtime, so I was planning to call out to a Lambda to perform the validation. However, I can't find any documentation on how to invoke a Lambda from a CF Edge Function.
I am aware of Lambda@Edge, but the throughput restrictions and lack of support for KeyValueStore make it somewhat unattractive.
So, is it possible to invoke a regular Lambda function via CF Functions?
If not, what are my caching options for Lambda@Edge?
